# Echo Stdin confusion

Tags: linux, bash, echo, stdout, stdin

I have created two files namely file1.txt and file2.txt.
When I write

```
echo < file1.txt
```

It returns an empty line. But `cat < file1.txt` returns the contents of the file1.txt.

Since echo prints whatever is sent to it, why is echo not printing the contents of the file1.txt?

Comment: What makes you think that echo "prints whatever is sent to it"? See `help echo` from a bash session.

Comment: Yes, I saw and came to know about my misunderstanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the duplicate and has been resolved: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63658/redirecting-the-content-of-a-file-to-the-command-echo

You can redirect all you want to `echo` but it won't do anything with it. `echo` doesn't read its standard input. All it does is write to standard output its arguments separated by a space character and terminated by a newline character (and with some `echo` implementations with some escape sequences in them expanded and/or arguments starting with `-` possibly treated as options).

If you want `echo` to display the content of a file, you have to pass that content as an argument to `echo`. Something like:

```
echo "$(cat my_file.txt)"
```

Note that `$(...)` strips the trailing newline characters from the output of that `cat` command, and `echo` adds **one** back.

Also note that except with `zsh`, you can't pass NUL characters in the arguments of a command, so that above will typically not work with binary files. `yash` will also remove bytes that don't form part of valid characters.

If the reason for wanting to do that is because you want `echo` to expand the `\n`, `\b`, `\0351`... escape sequences in the file (as UNIX conformant `echo` implementations do, but not all), then you'd rather use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(cat my_file.txt)"
```

Contrary to `echo`, that one is portable and won't have problems if the content of the file starts with `-`.